# Could I submit multiple apk file on google play for multiple target?

Tags: android, google-play

I'm tending to release and submit to GooglePlay two apk files of the same application. One with android sdk 7 for android version lower than 4.0, one with android sdk 14 for android 4.0 and upper. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes..It's easy. http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. But, it might be tricky.

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

There will be some problems, when you different apks for devices, which are close to each other. But, you can get started with the above link.

It's recommended though, to have a single apk.

Note: You should generally use multiple APKs to support different device configurations only when your APK is too large (greater than 50MB).